# Consume PHP web service in VB.net / ASP application

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I created a web service using NuSoap in PHP/APACHE. The service requires a client certificate and additional SOAP header with Username and Password element for authentication.

I am having trouble on consuming service with .net application. Any idea or references on how to send request supplying client certificate and adding soap header to web service reference?

(Note: SOAP Header is not yet included here, just trying if I can connect to the service.)

```
    Dim svc As UserAccountServices.UserAccountService = New UserAccountServices.UserAccountService

    Dim cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("D:\client.pem")
    Dim certPath = "D:\client.pem"

    Dim rawData As Byte() = ReadCertFile(certPath)
    cert.Import(rawData, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
    svc.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
    Dim result
    result = svc.UserAccountServicegetUserDetails("TestUser")
```

Encountered Error:
**The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**